# Is it reasonable to have both DomianService and Silverlight-enabled WCF Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

At the moment it seems that a RIA Domain Services class can not return a sinlge custom type.

There are parts of my app that needs just that, so think the only way to get that is to call back to a simple silverlight-enabled WCF Service, which i beleive will not have a problem returning a custom type.  I don't see where the Silverlight client app has any sort of reference to the Ria Services.  How do I set up both a Ria services and WCF service on the silverlight client.  Will the WCF service be "aware" of the authenication already in place with the RIA services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of my biggest bugbears of RIA Services :).  The good thing is that they are in the process of enabling complex types to be returned from invoke methods (according to the user voice site for RIA Services).  However, that won't help you now :).

The best way to implement your requirement to return complex objects is indeed to set up a standard WCF Service to return complex types when required.  You do so in the normal way that you would expose a WCF in any web project.  You then consume it in your Silverlight application in much the same way you would a WCF Service in any other type of project (by adding it as a service reference).  The main difference when consuming it (compared to other types of projects) is that Silverlight only supports asynchronous calls.  One difference to be aware of from RIA Services is that whereas RIA Services automatically determines the URI of the domain services (based upon where the XAP file originated from), you will need to handle that aspect yourself (very important when you try to deploy your application :).  Do this either by setting the URI in the app.config file, or use the method I use in the code accompanying this article here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Framework-for-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Applications.aspx.

In regards to your final question, yes, RIA Services uses standard ASP.NET authentication, so the cookie that it uses to maintain your authentication status is also used by any WCF Services in the same project.  I talk a bit about security with WCF Services in this article if you want more information: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Application-Part-3.aspx.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Comment: This is exactly the kind of confirmation I was looking for.  You mention the users voice site for RIA services, and wonder if you could include the URL for that.

Comment: Glad it helped :).  The site is http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services.  You'll find that "Support for Complex Types" is the #3 highest voted feature, and is marked as started :).